# Change to Timestamp format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, format

I am fetching datetime from DB which is stored as "03-MAR-20 02.46.13.716000000 PM" (Timestamp) and comes to UI in the  format "1583226973724". I want to convert this back to as how displayed in DB.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convert it to the exact same format as the one in the DB or a slightly different one?

Comment: I have converted into dd-mm-yyy hh:mm:ss format. Just looking if can be done in DB format

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle database